# Best approach for building an LSH table using Apache Beam and Dataflow

Tags: apache-beam, embedding, lsh

I have an LSH table builder utility class which goes as follows (referred from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/locality-sensitive-hashing-for-music-search-f2f1940ace23)):

```py
class BuildLSHTable:
    def __init__(self, hash_size=8, dim=2048, num_tables=10, lsh_file="lsh_table.pkl"):
        self.hash_size = hash_size
        self.dim = dim
        self.num_tables = num_tables
        self.lsh = LSH(self.hash_size, self.dim, self.num_tables)
        self.embedding_model = embedding_model
        self.lsh_file = lsh_file

    def train(self, training_files):
        for id, training_file in enumerate(training_files):
            image, label = training_file
            if len(image.shape) < 4:
                image = image[None, ...]
            features = self.embedding_model.predict(image)
            self.lsh.add(id, features, label)
        
        with open(self.lsh_file, "wb") as handle:
            pickle.dump(self.lsh, 
                        handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I then execute the following in order to build my LSH table:

```py
training_files = zip(images, labels)
lsh_builder = BuildLSHTable()
lsh_builder.train(training_files)
```

Now, when I am trying to do this via Apache Beam (code below), it's throwing:

```
TypeError: can't pickle tensorflow.python._pywrap_tf_session.TF_Operation objects
```

Code used for Beam:

```py
def generate_lsh_table(args):
    options = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions(**args)
    args = namedtuple("options", args.keys())(*args.values())

    with beam.Pipeline(args.runner, options=options) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | 'Build LSH Table' >> beam.Map(
                args.lsh_builder.train, args.training_files)
        )
```

This is how I am invoking the beam runner:

```py
args = {
    "runner": "DirectRunner",
    "lsh_builder": lsh_builder,
    "training_files": training_files
}

generate_lsh_table(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam pipelines should be converted to a standard (for example, proto) format before being executed. As a part of this certain pipeline objects such as `DoFn`s get serialized (picked). If your `DoFn`s have instance variables that cannot be serialized this process cannot continue.

One way to solve this is to load/define such instance objects or modules during execution instead of creating and storing such objects during pipeline submission. This might require adjusting your pipeline.

Comment: > This might require adjusting your pipeline. Could you share a few such adjustments?